# How to Modify a Font to Fixed Width in Fontlab

Tags: typefaces, font-design, monospace

I use a text user interface application on a server that I access via a Terminal. I have been using the [Futurist Fixed-width](https://www.dafont.com/futurist-fixed-width.font) for some time on a Linux PC in Gnome-Terminal, and would like to use that same font on a Windows PC with Putty.

When downloaded on a Windows PC, this font does not display as an option. I believe this is due to it not being correctly marked as a fixed-width font.

I have downloaded FontLab VI and attempted to mark this as a fixed-width font (Font Info > Monospaced), but it does not seem to be committing. When I open the exported font again in FontLab, I see that it again not marked as fixed-width.

I'd love to use this font in PuTTY, and am not committed to using any particular program to accomplish it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have *Allow selection of variable-pitched fonts* checked.

[image]

Also, bear in mind that changing the font would **IS NOa T** global setting, but rather a **per session** setting.